# How to decompile a ELF 32-bit LSB executable?

Tags: linux

I have a ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), which is also stripped, and I want to explore it. Does anyone know how to decompile such a file?

Comment: Use `readelf` and `objdump`. Without knowing what you're looking for precisely, it's hard to tell you how you could do it.

Comment: @Mat, thanks for your reply, I am just trying to find a password which is embedded in that file

Comment: You're on your own then. Good luck and don't do anything illegal.

Comment: what does this error means..
`readelf: Error: Unable to read in 0x2000000 bytes of string table
readelf: Error: no .dynamic section in the dynamic segment`
BTW its legal and its for a contest :P

Comment: You could try searching for something readable with `strings` command, but I doubt it will be that easy. You'll probably have to use some disassembler and try to understand the asm. For simple usages I'd recommend something lightweight, like ht editor. Also, you could use gdb, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698299/set-breakpoint-in-an-stripped-elf-executable. By the way, if it's for the contest, you shouldn't really ask for help, right? Anyway, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

[IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/index.shtml) plus [Hex-Rays decompiler](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/index.shtml) can [decompile](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/decompiler/compare_vs_disassembly.shtml) (to pseudo-C code) most of 32-bit x86 code, including Linux ELF files.

Disclaimer: I work for Hex-Rays.

Comment: What if we don't want to pay $2k+?

Comment: @IanM: you can try the alternatives offered in other answers/comments.